# ticking with several views per minute

Tags: support

I wonder if anyone can explain the viewing pattern at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566418/). It seems to receive clicks from some type of bot at the rate of several clicks per minute.

What do you suppose is causing this?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: It is in the network wide hot question list. Nothing unusual as far as I can see.